# What is the actual origin of the prefix 'bi-'?

Tags: etymology

How can anybody be sure the prefix 'bi-' (and its presumed source in Latin 'bis'= twice) did not originally come from Basque, in which the word for '2' is actually 'bi'?

Answer (score 3):

Because we can trace the origin of English *bi-* to Latin *bis* "twice", and from there back to Proto-Indo-European; and we know many cognate Indo-European words, such as Latin *duo* and English *two*. In Proto-Italic, *bis* was still **dwis*. The change of *dw* into *b* happened later, forming Latin *bis*.

I don't know anything about Basque except that it is a language isolate, possibly part of some larger pre-Indo-European linguistic family, but I would rather expect Basque to have borrowed this word from superstrate Indo-European languages (Celtic? Latin?) than the other way around.

Compare Latin *bellum* "war" (whence English *belligerent*), from an older root **dwe-*, which can still be seen in the alternative form *duellum*, whence English *duel*.

From De Vaan's etymological dictionary of Latin:

[image]